# Why is jq modify and if-then-else not working

Tags: jq

I want to modify values within a hash.  Sometimes the values are simple strings or numbers, and other times they are objects.

I can start with a simple example:

```
jq -n '{a:"string",b:{k:"k",v:1},c:12}'
```

which results in

```
{
  "a": "string",
  "b": {
    "k": "k",
    "v": 1
  },
  "c": 12
}
```

I want the value of the `b` key in the hash to get the value of `.v` below it (I actually want to do things more complex but it works for this example).

My attempt:

```
jq -n '
  {a:"string",b:{k:"k",v:1},c:12} |
  with_entries(.value|=if .v? then .v else . end)
'
```

outputs:

```
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 1,
  "c": null
}
```

I see the value of `b` becomes 1 as expected, but when `.v` does not exist, it causes the entire value to become null instead of `.` as I expected.

This does not appear to be specific to the `.foo?` operation either.

```
jq -n '
  {a:"string",b:{k:"k",v:1},c:12} |
  with_entries(.value|=if (.|strings) then . else . end)
'
```

outputs

```
{
  "a": "string",
  "b": null,
  "c": null
}
```

Any idea how I can have complex logic for updating .value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.v?` only returns `null` if `.` is an object that *could* have a key `v`, but doesn't; otherwise, it evaluates to no value at all.

```
$ jq -n '{a:1}.v?'
null
$ jq -n '"foo".v?'
$
```

With nothing to test, the `if-then-else` expression *also* has no value at all, which results in `.value` being removed from the input to `with_entries`.

Likewise, `.|strings` filters out non-string values entirely; it doesn't provide a false or null for each element of `.` that *isn't* a string. Any array is true, so the `then` value is always returned, but only for string-valued values. Otherwise, *no* value is returned, and `.value` is again removed.

`objects` can be used, but on the *left* of `|=`, not the right. You want to disregard non-objects from even being updated, rather than trying to replace it with itself if it isn't an object with `v`.

```
jq -n '
  {a:"string",b:{k:"k",v:1},c:12} |
  with_entries((.value|objects) |= if .v then .v else . end)
'
```

There's no further need for `.v?`; if you are sure that all objects *will* have a `v` key, you can dispense with the `if-then-else` expression as well.

Comment: Your mention of `evaluates to no value at all` is a pretty big clue why it was not working.  I have since used `type` to deal with simple objects before handling arrays and objects separately.  I guess I may still have an edge case where I have a 'value' that is an object but not the .foo? key inside.  Those likely evaluate to no value at all.

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you expected :

```
jq -n '{a:"string",b:{k:"k",v:1},c:12}|.b |= .v'
```

If you want to keep the structure of you script, add object test :

```
jq -n '
  {a:"string",b:{k:"k",v:1},c:12} |
  with_entries(.value|=(if type == "object" and .v? then .v else . end))
'
```

Comment: I wanted to do a lot more than just reference .v, but the key result shown in your answer seems to have been the use of `type == "object"` which is how I ended up getting this to work.